# How do you drop Undefined elements from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose `v[w,y]` is a function and consider the following solution for w:

```
solw = Solve[v[w,y]==0,w,Reals];
w[y]:= N[w/.solw]
```

I need to use `w[y]` in a number of other calculations before I substitute in a value for `y`.  However, if I substitute a value for `y` in at this point, the resulting list contains `Undefined` elements, e.g.: `w[y]/.y->20` yields:

```
{-2.53, -1.534,23.2,Undefined,Undefined}
```

The last two elements screw up my future calculations.  As a very simple example (not the one I am working on, but simple enough to present here), suppose I want to compute:`f[y]=w[y]^2 + 2y`. Is there a way to define `w[y]` now so that the undefined elements are dropped from the list in any future calculations such as `f[y]`?  For the specific problem I am working on, it would be MUCH easier to deal with this problem BEFORE computing `f[x]`.  Thanks!

Comment: `list /. Undefined -> Nothing` might do it.

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, Undefined]` or `Select[list, NumericQ]` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  These work when I apply them after having first evaluated the function at a particular value of y, but not when i evaluate the value of y later.